# I don't get why this is true $W \subset H \iff H^{\perp} \subset W^{\perp}$ can someone explain?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having difficulty being convinced with this propriety of orthogonality $W \subset H \iff H^{\perp} \subset W^{\perp}$.

How can $H^⊥$ be included in $W^{\perp}$ if $W$ is included in $H$ it seems counterintuitive, can someone explain to me how come this is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $W \subset H$, then every formula that is satisfied by every element of $H$ is also satisfied by every element of $W$. In particular, every vector orthogonal to $H$ is automatically orthogonal to $W$, and that means $H^\perp \subset W^\perp$.

Symbolicaly:
\begin{align} (W \subset H) \Rightarrow & \;\forall v :\big((\forall u\in H: \langle v|u\rangle = 0) \Rightarrow ((\forall u\in W: \langle v|u\rangle = 0)\big) \\
&\Leftrightarrow \forall v : \big((v \in H^\perp) \Rightarrow (v \in W^\perp)\big) \\
&\Leftrightarrow H^\perp \subset W^\perp\end{align}

Using $(V^\perp)^\perp = V$ (which is true for vector subspaces, but not for general subsets), you can show implication in the other direction.

Answer (score 2):

If $\omega$ is orthogonal to all elements of $H$ then it is also orthogonal to all elements in $W$ since $W$ is a subset of $H$ (i.e. every element of $W$ is also an element of $H$). Therefore 
$$ H^\perp \subset W^\perp.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let us concentrate on $$W ⊂ H ⇒ H^⊥ ⊂ W^⊥$$.

If $v\in H^⊥$ then $v$ is perpendicular to everything in $H$

We know that $W ⊂ H$ therefore $v$ is perpendicular to everything in $W$

That means $v\in W^⊥ $

The rest of the proof is similar.

Answer (score 0):

Let $W \subset H$, and let $x \in W^{\perp}$. Then $\langle x,y \rangle=0$ for all $y \in W$. But since $W \subset H$, for all $y \in W$ we have $y \in H$. Hence $\langle x,y \rangle=0 , \forall y \in H$ as well, so by definition $x \in H^{\perp}$.

Answer (score 0):

For one direction suppose $W\subset H$. Let $x\in H^\perp$. Then $x$ is orthogonal to every vector in $H$ and in particular every vector in $W$ since $W\subset H$. Hence $H^\perp\subset W^\perp$. For the converse apply the forward direction and use the fact that $(H^\perp)^\perp =H$.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this gives you some intuition:

Take $R^3$. Draw some plane $H$ going through the origin, and a line $W$ on that plane going through the origin. Now, look at $H^\perp$ and $W^\perp$.
$H^\perp$ is the *line* perpendicular to all lines in H, in particular, to $W$. Thus, $H^\perp\subset W^\perp$, $W^\perp$ being the *plane* perpendicular to $W$.